# Spark sql query returns StringType instead of ArrayType?

Tags: apache-spark-sql

In trying to apply my UDF during my spark.sql query, instead of returning my cleaned words in array form the query simply returns one long string that looks like my array. This gives me an error when attempting to apply CountVectorizer. The error it raises is `'requirement failed: Column cleanedWords must be of type equal to one of the following types: [ArrayType(StringType,true), ArrayType(StringType,false)] but was actually of type StringType.'`

This is my code:

```
from string import punctuation
from hebrew import stop_words
hebrew_stopwords = stop_words()

def removepuncandstopwords(listofwords):
    newlistofwords = []
    for word in listofwords:
        if word not in hebrew_stopwords:
            for punc in punctuation:
                word = word.strip(punc)
            newlistofwords.append(word)
    return newlistofwords

from pyspark.ml.feature import CountVectorizer, IDF, Tokenizer, Normalizer
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType

sqlctx.udf.register("removepuncandstopwords", removepuncandstopwords, ArrayType(StringType()))

sentenceData = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0, "Hello my friend; i am sam"),
    (1, "Hello, my name is sam")
], ["label", "sentence"])

tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol="sentence", outputCol="words")
wordsData = tokenizer.transform(sentenceData)
wordsData.registerTempTable("wordsData")
wordsDataCleaned = spark.sql("select label, sentence, words, removepuncandstopwords(words) as cleanedWords from wordsData")



wordsDataCleaned[['cleanedWords']].rdd.take(2)[0]
Out[163]:
Row(cleanedWords='[hello, my, friend, i, am, sam]')
```

How can i resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

So I just came across this error as well. So the way the documents want the data structured is

```
cleanedWords=['hello', 'my', 'friend', 'is', 'sam']
```

However yours seems to be different. So instead of this

```
sentenceData = spark.createDataFrame([
(0, "Hello my friend; i am sam"),
(1, "Hello, my name is sam")],
["label", "sentence"])
```

I believe it should be this

```
documentDF = spark.createDataFrame([
(0, "Hello my friend; i am sam".split(" "), ),
(1, "Hello, my name is sam".split(" "),],
["label", "sentence"])
```

Source: I am just going off the docs where they structured their code like

```
documentDF = spark.createDataFrame([
("Hi I heard about Spark".split(" "), ),
("I wish Java could use case classes".split(" "), ),
("Logistic regression models are neat".split(" "), )
], ["text"])
```

Link - https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/ml-features.html#word2vec